# Binomial series convergence proof using differentiation

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, power-series, binomial-coefficients

A homework problem is asking me to prove that $(1 + x)^{q}$ is equal to the binomial series on $[-1,1]$ but I am supposed to do so by proving the following statement:

$$
(1 + x)^{-q} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {q \choose n} x^{n} = 1 , |x| < 1
$$

It gives a hint saying that I am supposed to differentiate this, but I am confused on how that helps at all. What am I supposed to realize to be able to prove that this quotient equals $1$? Am I forgetting some sort of identity?

Comment: After differentiation, the RHS becomes zero and you should be able to show that this matches the derivative of the LHS. To prove that the expression is $1$, it suffices to set $x=0$

Comment: @YvesDaoust Thank you. I see the logic in that. I am having trouble simplifying the RHS  after taking the derivative however.